# Spring Security: antMatchers not matching URL pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Out of the blue, the security of my application is broken. It doesn't match the patterns in `antMatchers.(<patterns>).permitAll()`, and is trying to authenticate all the URLs. Code below

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());
}

@Bean
public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preauthAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper());
    return preauthAuthProvider;
}

@Bean
public HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter ssoFilter() throws Exception {
    HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter filter = new HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter();
    filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("user_id");
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetSer = new CustomUserDetailsService();
    userDetSer.setUserService(userService);
    filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
    filter.setCustomUserDetailsService(userDetSer);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

    return filter;
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsServiceWrapper() {

    CustomUserDetailsService userDetSer = new CustomUserDetailsService();
    userDetSer.setUserService(userService);

    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>();
    wrapper.setUserDetailsService(userDetSer);
    return wrapper;
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider());

    httpSecurity
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(httpAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/", "/applogin", "/login", "/logout", "/verify**", "/verify/**", "/pub/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/signin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/signin")
                    .failureUrl("/signin?error")
                    .permitAll()
                    .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout").invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
}
```

I'm trying to access `{{url}}/applogin`. Below is the log

```
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /applogin at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /applogin at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /applogin at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@49168180
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /applogin at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/signout', GET]
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /applogin' doesn't match 'GET /signout
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/signout', POST]
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/applogin'; against '/signout'
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/signout', PUT]
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /applogin' doesn't match 'PUT /signout
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/signout', DELETE]
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /applogin' doesn't match 'DELETE /signout
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /applogin at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter'
 INFO 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] t.l.c.w.HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter    : Authenticating [POST /applogin]
...
< application logs >
...
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG 17458 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

I'm using Spring security version 4.2.1

Comment: What did you change? I would say, it never worked. There is a difference between authentication and authorization. Your  `HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter` makes the authentication (which is too broad) and Spring makes the authorization (as configured in your configuration).

Comment: So you're saying the code is buggy? The application actually has been running over a year now, but I got my hands on it a couple weeks back. I'd made a few changes to the code in an attempt to improve the code standards. But I'm not strong on Spring security. Hence the problems.

Comment: Nothing more than some refactoring in `HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter`.

Comment: Do you apply the filter for all URLs or is there any `if` statement in `HeaderPreAuthProcessingFilter` for a special URL?